# Оптимизация сцен с большим кол-вом объектов с Dynamic Rigidbody2D в Unity

Tags: unity3d

Проблема в следующем: в 2D сцене пытаюсь создать много разрушаемых "коробок". При разрушении нижней коробки, та, что стоит выше, должна падать вниз. Естественно, для этого я использую компонент Rigidbody2D, что, в свою очередь, вызывает кучу расчетов по физике(каждая коробка стоит на другой коробке, получается куча взаимодействующих между собой rigidbody), что приводит к весьма ощутимой потере в производительности. **Можно ли каким-либо образом минимизировать потерю производительности при таком подходе?** Я думаю, что существует некий способ оптимизации подобных "конструкций", однако найти ничего, к сожалению, не смог. Буду рад любым советам на эту тему.

Comment: Если просто ровно переместится в низ, то  можно без физики. Когда убираешь коробку, то перемещаешь ту что над ней, на ее место. Если реалистично, то ставь меньше коробок.

Comment: @ValeraKvip хотелось бы, чтобы коробка летела до земли, т.е. падала, а не перемещалась, т.к. визуально это смотрится так себе

Comment: Если надо что бы она падала и ударялась  другие, крутилась и тд, то меньше коробок. Если просто падать в низ, то транслейтом можно(просто проскользит вниз) и никакую физику можно тогда не вешать.

Answer (score 2):

Если тебе не нужны коллизии между ящиками в покоящемся состоянии можно отрубить у них физику, кинематик, гравитацию убрать, коллайдеры вырубить. Повесить на стену 1 большой коллайдер. Если ты стреляешь по ящикам или просто бьешь их, то при взаимодействии, например пострелял через райкаст, определил через точку ближайший ящик, уничтожил его, включил физику на ящиках, как только они остановятся, проделываешь тоже самое.

Если ящики по физике должны падать просто вниз, то сделай матрицу из ящиков, и только в столбе, где уничтожился ящик включаешь физику.

Тут много вариантов можно придумать, все зависит от задачи и как это все выглядеть должно